# No login panel when using .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, security

I have password protected a folder on the server with .htaccess.
However, when I type the url of that folder, I get a 404 message instead of the expected login panel.
Apparantly this is not a common problem since I don't come across this issue in search engines.
Anybody out there who can get me on track?
Edit:
The content of .htaccess is:

```
AuthUserFile /home/my_root/.htpasswdaprotect
AuthName "Please Log In"
AuthType Basic
require user Els
```

The .htaccess file is in the folder that I want to password protect.

Server information is as follows:
Apache Version: 2.4.12
PHP Version: 5.4.42
MySQL Version: 5.5.46-cll
Architecture: x86_64
Operating System: linux

Comment: Add the contents of your .htaccess file to the question.

Comment: You may have wrong web server configuration. We need more details.

Comment: Thanks Jack and Mehmet. I have added the info.